# Why IConfiguration object always return null in .net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I have this Dblayer class.

I am trying to read the connection string from the app.setting.

Here is my class

```
public class DbLayer
{
        [Inject]
        private static IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

        public DbLayer()
        {
        }

        public DbLayer(IConfiguration _configuration)
        {
            Configuration = _configuration;
        }

        public const string CONNECTION_STRING_NAME = "CustomersDatabase";

        private static string _connectionString = string.Empty;

        public static string ConnectionString
        {
            get
            {
                if (_connectionString == string.Empty)
                {
                    _connectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=CustomersRegistrations;" +
                        "Integrated Security=SSPI; " +
                        "Encrypt=False;";
                    _connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString(CONNECTION_STRING_NAME);
                }

                return _connectionString;
            }
        }
}
```

In my startup class, I have the following:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
```

The problem is `Configuration` object is always null...

Any reason for that?

Comment: Where is `Confiugration` `null`, in `Startup` or in `DbLayer`?

Comment: @Alexander DbLayer class. I know I can fix it using the Confiugration  in stratup class by changing the property to static one. However I just want to know why my injection is not working ?

Comment: It would be helpful to have a reproducible sample project because everything works fine for me with the code you shared